# How to fetch JSON content from web to our program

Tags: android, android-webservice

I am a newbie to android and I started to work with JSON and don't know why they use HTTP, etc,

Doubt 1:I am pretty confused as sometimes they use DefaultHttpClient and some other time they use Httpclient

Doubt 2:
I saw two syntax used for same operation
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"),8);

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputstream));

any additional explanation on this is also helpful for me

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at google volley which is a HTTPClient lib for android made by google which helps you a lot on json calls, also have a look at gson (a json deserielizer from google)

Comment: Use asynhttpclient its pretty simple to use. for parsing json google library is there gson.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer this two link
Json Paring:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Http Client
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"),8);
"UTF-8" means encoding from received string